# Cutting String by using regexp

Tags: java

I want to cut the string using regexp, but not to cut the regexp part...

```
String path ="house/room/cabinet/my_books/bought/2011/adventure/Black-Ship01/312 pages/...";
String[] substract=path.split("my_");
path=substract1[1].toString();// books/bought/2011/adventure/Black-Ship01/312 pages/...
String[] substract2=path.split("-Ship.."); //split using -Ship and two random simbols
path=substract[1].toString();

RESULT:   path= "books/bought/2011/adventure/Black"
Should be path= "books/bought/2011/adventure/Black-Ship01"
```

so how to add -Ship01 ??

Comment: Please learn how formatting works on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [positive lookbehind](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum): `String[] substract2=path.split("(?<=-Ship..)")`. This matches the pattern but doesn't consume the characters.

Comment: doesnt work i get books/bought/2011/adventure/Black-Ship0  the 1 is missing?1

Comment: @user615927 - @aix code is correct. Just tested it and the `substract2[0]` ends with `Ship01`.

Comment: Damn your rigth i accidentally have written substract2[0].toString().trim(LOL).split("?=-Ship");

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a better way right now. But you could do something like that:

```
public class NewClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String finalStr = "";
        String patternStr = "(-Ship..)";
        String path ="house/room/cabinet/my_books/bought/2011/adventure/Black-Ship01/312 pages/...";
        String[] substract2 = path.split(patternStr);       
        System.out.println("substract2="+Arrays.toString(substract2));      
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(path);    
        matcher.find();
        System.out.println("g0="+matcher.group(0));
        finalStr = substract2[0]+matcher.group(0);
        System.out.println("finalStr="+finalStr);
      }     
}
```

Enjoy, Boro.